# Kannel sms gateway

Tags: php

I've implemented the kannel and I can send sms and receive sms successfully. But I want to send sms from mobile to kannel. I will call the php file for parsing the sms string and then send to the url in get-url variable. I want to receive sms .php function. Here is my php script for parsing the string sms.

```
<?php 
     $rawPhoneNumber = "2+2=?; 4;5;6;3; 4; PTBB; 4,2,1,2";
     $phoneChunks = explode(";", $rawPhoneNumber);
     echo "Raw Phone Number = $rawPhoneNumber <br />";
     echo "Questions = $phoneChunks[0]<br />";
     for($i = 1; $i < count($phoneChunks)-3; $i++)
     {
         echo "Ans ($i) = $phoneChunks[$i] <br />";
     }    
     echo "Correct Answer = $phoneChunks[5]<br />";
     echo " Curriculum= $phoneChunks[6]<br />";
     echo "SLO = $phoneChunks[7]";
?>
```

Comment: Code is a mess and your question is unclear. Don't put variables into strings the way you do, do it properly: `echo "Question = " . $phoneChunks[0] . "<br />";`

Comment: i want to send this sms from mobile to kannel. the sms is send to kannel  i want that kannel use receivesms.php functio to parse the entire sms and redirect to the get-url @Rameez

Comment: @user3756274 did you find any solutions?.